# Xcode: Why does my flip animation flip twice?

Tags: xcode, uigesturerecognizer, flip

I'm having a little problem. I have an UILabel which have an UILongPressGestureRecognicer. When the UILongPressGestureRecognizer is called my app is supposed to switch to a new view using a flip animation.

This is the code I have used for the GestureRecognizer:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *labelLongPressRecognizer;
labelLongPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LoadLabelSettings:)];

labelLongPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
labelLongPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;

[NewLabel addGestureRecognizer:labelLongPressRecognizer];
```

and this is the code for the view switching animation:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:LabelSettingsViewController.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];

if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

    LabelSettingsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 300);

}
```

My problem is that when I hold down on my UILabel the switch animation begins, but when I release it repeats the animation again. So basically the animation occur twice and I only want it to take place once.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the sender state, e.g.,

```
- (void)LoadLabelSettings:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) // or whatever
        // then do the flipping stuff
}
```

Check out the "Overview" of the "UILongPressGestureRecognizer Class Reference", which talks about the long press being continuous and I presume numerous events could be triggered:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html